# Core Data: Building on Device causes an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator error

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, ios-simulator

I just build a simple application using Core Data to retrieve data from a preloaded SQLite database (created by the app itself when running in the Simulator). After populating the database I run the application on the iPhone Simulator and everything seamed to go just fine but when I run it on the device I got the following error message:

> Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if your xcdatamodel(d) file is linked with your target? This can happen when there is no xcdatamodel(d) is not present inside the .app bundle.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I previously had the model accidentally deleted but managed to get it back somehow. It seems the connection was not restored properly anyway. I resolved by deleting the model and writing a new one from sketch and adding all the entities and properties I needed.